# Npm Run Dev Doesn't Work Properly Font awesome Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, npm, import

This is the error i get after importing @fortawesome

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
   ╷
16 │ @import "~@fortawesome";
   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  C:\xampp\htdocs\renazaandam\resources\sass\app.scss 16:9  root stylesheet
```

Answer (score 0):

To install font-awesome you first should install it with npm. So in your project root directory type:

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

Then edit the resources`/assets/sass/app.scss` file and add at the top this line:

```
@import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

Now you can do for example:

```
npm run dev
```

This builds unminified versions of the resources in the correct folders. If you wanted to minify them, you would instead run:

```
npm run production
```

And then you can use the font.